# Flash function on custom class not recognized

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new in flash programming and I'm trying to add some member function in movie clip class. What I've done is right click on my movie clip, and edit class.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class cupu extends MovieClip {


    public function cupu() {
        // constructor code
    }
    public function myMathFunction(intParameter:int):int{ 
        return(intParameter * 5); 
    } 
}
```

I added MyMathFunction. 
But, when I try to call:

```
var kroco:cupu;
kroco = new cupu();
trace(kroco.myMathFunction(5));
```

I got an error message:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: myMathFunction is not a function.
at Kecoa_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

When I press ctrl+ space, MyMathFunction is actually appeared. Can someone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your code is missing a bracket, but i assume you do have it in your original code, otherwise it's a perfectly normal as3 class which did work for me.

Let's try to crack this:

1. What Flash IDE version you're using?
2. Do you have any other code in that frame? If yes, try moving instantation of cupu and trace statement to other frame.

Mabye you're trying to access myMathFunction somwhere else - let's say on a regular movieclip not instance of cupu class?

Comment: I'm using flash CS6. The class function, I saved as test.as in the same directory with the .fla file. Should I include the test.as file manually into flash? Or the .fla file will automatically recognize?

Comment: If it didn't find your class then you would get an exception on the type declaration before the function. Do you have multiple things called cupu? Have you create a library object with that name?

Comment: In my library, I have movieclip with AS Linkage named cupu. When I change that AS Linkage class name from property, it works and no error. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the parenthesis in the **return** statment? Maybe this solve the problem, just like this:

```
public function myMathFunction(intParameter:int):int{ 
    return intParameter*5; 
}
```